# Erro ao separar a camada de dados (AparelhoDAO) da classe principal (Home)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile

package com.energycalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import java.util.List;

public class Home extends Activity {

```
BDaparelho dbHelper = null;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;

List<Aparelho> aparelhoList;
ListView listViewDevice;
double ResultM;
boolean showRegistrationTable = false;

EditText editTextNome;
EditText editTextConsumo;
EditText editTextTempo;
EditText editTextQtd;
TextView lblConsumoDiario;

Button btnRegister;
TableLayout registrationTable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    fillComponents();
    updateHome();

}

//----Criação do Menu acessado pelo botão de menu do Aparelho (Não implementado)----//
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

//----método que chama o Simular conta----//
private static final int Activity_Simular_Conta = 1;

public void SimularConta(View view) {
    Intent it = new Intent(view.getContext(), SimularConta.class);
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putDouble("ResultM", ResultM);
    it.putExtras(params);
    startActivityForResult(it, Activity_Simular_Conta);
}

//----Preenche os componentes buscando o id no XML home e define os OnClick para a Lista----/
private void fillComponents() {

    //----Campos----//
    editTextNome = findViewById(R.id.editTextNome);
    editTextQtd = findViewById(R.id.editTextQtd);
    editTextConsumo = findViewById(R.id.editTextConsumo);
    editTextTempo = findViewById(R.id.editTextTempo);
    lblConsumoDiario = findViewById(R.id.lblConsumoDiario);
    registrationTable = findViewById(R.id.device_registration);

    //----Button----//
    btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btn_registration);


    //----ListView----//
    listViewDevice = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listViewDevice.getLayoutParams().height = 1200;
    listViewDevice.setScrollContainer(true);

    //Chama o método que mostra os campos
    registrationTable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    showRegistrationTable = true;

    //----Banco de Dados----//
    //dbHelper = new BDaparelho(getApplicationContext());

    //----OnClickListeners (Define a ação do objeto quando o usuário clicar na lista "edit")----//
    listViewDevice.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(Home.this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.edit_aparelho, null);

            final EditText editNome = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText_TE);
            final EditText editQtd = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText_TU);
            final EditText editConsumo = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText_ICMS);
            final EditText editTempoUso = textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.editText_PIS);

            final Aparelho item = aparelhoList.get(position);

            editNome.setText(item.getnome());
            editQtd.setText(String.valueOf(item.getqtd()));
            editConsumo.setText(String.valueOf(item.getConsumo()));
            editTempoUso.setText(String.valueOf(item.gettime()));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);

            builder.setView(textEntryView);

            editNome.requestFocus();

            //----Implementação do botão "Cancelar" na tela de "edit"----//
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                }
            });
            //----Implementação do botão "Salvar" na tela de "edit" e validação dos campos ----//
            builder.setPositiveButton("Salvar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                }
            });

            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                //-----Valida os campos na tela de edição apenas----//
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editNome.getText().toString())) {
                        editNome.setError("Preencha o nome!");
                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editQtd.getText().toString())) {
                        editQtd.setError("Preencha a Quantidade!");
                    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editQtd.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                        editQtd.setError("Digite quantidade maior que 0!");
                    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editQtd.getText().toString()) > 50) {
                        editQtd.setError("Quantidade máxima de 50!");
                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editConsumo.getText().toString())) {
                        editConsumo.setError("Preencha o Consumo!");
                    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editConsumo.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                        editConsumo.setError("Digite consumo maior que 0!");
                    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTempoUso.getText().toString())) {
                        editTempoUso.setError("Preencha o Tempo!");
                    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editTempoUso.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
                        editTempoUso.setError("Digite ao menos 1 hora!");
                    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editTempoUso.getText().toString()) > 24) {
                        editTempoUso.setError("O dia só tem 24 horas!");

                    } else {

                        item.setnome(editNome.getText().toString());
                        item.setqtd(Integer.parseInt(editQtd.getText().toString()));
                        item.setConsumo(Double.parseDouble(editConsumo.getText().toString()));
                        item.settime(Double.parseDouble(editTempoUso.getText().toString()));

                        //----Cria instancia para acessar o método persitItem na----/
                        //----classe AparelhoDAO passando item como parametro----/
                        AparelhoDAO aparelhoList = new AparelhoDAO();
                        aparelhoList.persistItem(item);


                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //----OnClickListeners (Define a ação do objeto quando o usuário clicar na lista e segurar "delete")----//
    listViewDevice.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int pos, long id) {
           final Aparelho item = aparelhoList.get(pos);

            String msg = "Aparelho selecionado: " + item.getnome();

            Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Home.this);
            alert.setTitle("Deletar Aparelho");
            alert.setMessage(msg);
            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", null);
            alert.setPositiveButton("Deletar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    //----Cria instancia para acessar o método deleteItem na classe AparelhoDAO----//
                    AparelhoDAO aparelhoDAO = new AparelhoDAO();
                    aparelhoDAO.deleteItem(item.getId());


                    updateHome();
                }
            });

            alert.show();

            return true;
        }
    });

    listViewDevice.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }

            // Handle ListView touch events.
            v.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });

    //----Oculta ou exibe os campos ao clicar no botão de cadastro----//
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (showRegistrationTable) {
                registrationTable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                showRegistrationTable = false;
            } else {
                registrationTable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                showRegistrationTable = true;
            }
        }
    });
}

//----Método do onClick do Botão "Salvar Aparelho"----//
public void diario(View view) {

    if (isValidFields()) {

        hideKeyboard();

        String nome = editTextNome.getText().toString();

        double consumo1 = Double.parseDouble(editTextConsumo.getText().toString());
        int quantidade1 = Integer.parseInt(editTextQtd.getText().toString());
        double tempo1 = Double.parseDouble(editTextTempo.getText().toString());

        Aparelho item = new Aparelho(nome, quantidade1, consumo1, tempo1);

        //----Cria instancia para acessar o método persitItem na classe AparelhoDAO----//

        AparelhoDAO aparelhoList = new AparelhoDAO();
        aparelhoList.persistItem(item);

    }
}

//----Validação para ver se os campos não estão nulos----//
private boolean isValidFields() {

    boolean ret = true;

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextNome.getText().toString())) {
        editTextNome.setError("Preencha o nome!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextQtd.getText().toString())) {
        editTextQtd.setError("Preencha a Quantidade!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editTextQtd.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
        editTextQtd.setError("Digite quantidade maior que 0!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (Integer.parseInt(editTextQtd.getText().toString()) > 50) {
        editTextQtd.setError("Quantidade máxima de 50!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextConsumo.getText().toString())) {
        editTextConsumo.setError("Preencha o Consumo!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editTextConsumo.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
        editTextConsumo.setError("Digite consumo maior que 0!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextTempo.getText().toString())) {
        editTextTempo.setError("Preencha o Tempo!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editTextTempo.getText().toString()) <= 0) {
        editTextTempo.setError("Digite ao menos 1 hora!");
        ret = false;
    } else if (Double.parseDouble(editTextTempo.getText().toString()) > 24) {
        editTextTempo.setError("O dia só tem 24 horas!");
        ret = false;
    }
    return ret;
}

//----Faz o cálculo do gasto total diário de todos os aparelhos cadastrados----//
public void calcularConsumoTotal() {

    double soma = 0;
    for (Aparelho aparelho : aparelhoList) {
        soma += aparelho.getvalortotal();
    }

    lblConsumoDiario.setText("Consumo Diário: " + String.format("%.2f", soma) + " kw");
    ResultM = soma;

}


//----Esconde o teclado do aplicativo----//
public void hideKeyboard() {

    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();

    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }

}

//----Atualiza a Lista e a Soma do Consumo Total----//
public void updateHome() {
    //----Atualiza a listView depois de criar o novo aparelho no Banco----//
    //----Call the getAparelhoList() method using the instance----//
    AparelhoDAO dao = new AparelhoDAO();
    aparelhoList = dao.getAparelhoList();
    listViewDevice.setAdapter(new AparelhoAdapter(Home.this, aparelhoList));
    calcularConsumoTotal();
}
```

}
package com.energycalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**

- -------------- Métodos da camada de dados --------------
  **/
  // Nome aparelho DAO (Data Access Object)
  //extend Activity porque alguns elementos como context dependem da activity

public class AparelhoDAO extends Activity {

```
BDaparelho dbHelper = null;
SQLiteDatabase db = null;
EditText editTextNome;
EditText editTextConsumo;
EditText editTextTempo;
EditText editTextQtd;



//Construtor
public AparelhoDAO() {


    dbHelper = new BDaparelho(getApplicationContext());
}

//----Método que faz o select no banco e devolve a lista de Aparelhos----//
public ArrayList<Aparelho> getAparelhoList() {
    db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM aparelho ORDER BY nm_aparelho", null);

    ArrayList<Aparelho> aparelhos = new ArrayList<Aparelho>();

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        aparelhos.add(fillAparelho(cursor));
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return aparelhos;
}

//----Método que recebe o cursor gerado pelo banco e devolve um Aparelho----//
private Aparelho fillAparelho(Cursor cursor) {

    Aparelho ret = new Aparelho();

    try {

        ret.setId(cursor.getLong(0));
        ret.setnome(cursor.getString(1));
        ret.setqtd(cursor.getInt(2));
        ret.setConsumo(cursor.getDouble(3));
        ret.settime(cursor.getInt(4));
        ret.setvalortotal(cursor.getDouble(5));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("Main", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return ret;
}

//----PersistItem verifica se o item já existe no banco para saber se é insert ou update----//
public void persistItem(Aparelho item) {


    //----Converte a primeira do texto em maiúscula----//
    item.setnome(item.getnome().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase(new Locale("pt", "BR")) + item.getnome().substring(1));

    //----Efetua os calculos com base nos dados do usuário----//
    item.setvalortotal(((item.getConsumo() * item.getqtd() * item.gettime()) / 1000));

    if (getById(item.getId()) == null) {
        insertItem(item);
        //----Limpa os Campos após armazenar no banco----//
        editTextNome.getText().clear();
        editTextConsumo.getText().clear();
        editTextTempo.getText().clear();
        editTextQtd.getText().clear();
    } else {
        updateItem(item);
    }
    //----Cria instancia para acessar o método updateHome na classe home----//
    Home home = new Home();
    home.updateHome();
}

//----getById serve para verificar se o aparelho já existe no banco----//
public Aparelho getById(long id) {
    Aparelho ret = null;

    try {
        //----Método que grava os dados no banco----//
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM aparelho WHERE id_aparelho = " + id + " ORDER BY nm_aparelho", null);

        if (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            ret = fillAparelho(cursor);
        }
        cursor.close();

        db.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(ex.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
    }

    return ret;
}

//----Insere um novo item no banco----//
private void insertItem(Aparelho item) {
    try {

        //----Método que grava os dados no banco----//
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        StringBuilder insertSQL = new StringBuilder();
        insertSQL.append("INSERT INTO");
        insertSQL.append(" aparelho(nm_aparelho,vl_qtd,vl_consumoWatts,vl_tempoConsumo,vl_totalAparelhoDia)");
        insertSQL.append(" VALUES(");
        insertSQL.append(" '" + item.getnome() + "'");
        insertSQL.append(" ," + item.getqtd());
        insertSQL.append(" ," + item.getConsumo());
        insertSQL.append(" ," + item.gettime());
        insertSQL.append(" ," + item.getvalortotal());
        insertSQL.append(")");

        db.execSQL(insertSQL.toString());

        db.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(ex.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
    }
}

//----Atualiza um item que já existe no banco----//
private void updateItem(Aparelho item) {
    try {

        //----método que grava os dados no banco----//
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        StringBuilder updateSQL = new StringBuilder();

        updateSQL.append("UPDATE APARELHO");
        updateSQL.append(" SET nm_aparelho = '" + item.getnome() + "'");
        updateSQL.append(" ,vl_qtd = " + item.getqtd());
        updateSQL.append(" ,vl_consumoWatts = " + item.getConsumo());
        updateSQL.append(" ,vl_tempoConsumo = " + item.gettime());
        updateSQL.append(" ,vl_totalAparelhoDia = " + item.getvalortotal());
        updateSQL.append(" WHERE id_aparelho = " + item.getId());

        db.execSQL(updateSQL.toString());

        db.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(ex.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
    }
}

//----Deleta um item acessado atraves do Click Longo na linha do item na lista----//
public void deleteItem(long id) {
    try {
        String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM APARELHO WHERE id_aparelho = " + id;

        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL(deleteSQL);

        db.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(ex.getMessage()).setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Esta é uma exceção de tempo de execução Java que ocorreu em um aplicativo Android. A exceção ocorreu ao tentar iniciar a atividade "Home" no pacote "com.energycalc". A causa raiz da exceção é uma NullPointerException que ocorreu no construtor da classe AparelhoDAO. A mensagem de erro indica que houve uma tentativa de invocar o método getApplicationContext() em uma referência de objeto nulo. Isso significa que a instância ContextWrapper na qual o método getApplicationContext() foi chamado era nula. Mas não sei como resolver...